# Implementing search function in UICollectionView in a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uisearchbar

I want to implement a search function in UICollectionView in a UICollectionViewCell.
What i'm trying to achieve is a swipe-able pages with search bar.
Previously i achieved multiple pages with a search bar but not able to swipe and to match with my Android application i need to make it swipe-able.
This is the tutorial i followed on how to make it swipe-able
https://www.letsbuildthatapp.com/course_video?id=75

To make this sound less confusing, the main UICollectionView let's call it MainFrame and the MainFrame stores the two UICollectionViewCell which contains their own UICollectionView let's call it ChildFrame.

So i'm able to parse search text from MainFrame to the ChildFrame and filter the data array in the ChildFrame. Checking it on the console log, everything is working as intended. The filtered result is correct. But my ChildFrame is not updating to the latest data array. Here's the code below.

**Here's the code for ChildFrame**

```swift
class ChildFrameCell1: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    let cellId = "cellId"

    var dataArray = [CustomObject]()

    var filteredData = [CustomObject]()

    var isFiltering: Bool = false

    var mainFrame: MainFrame?

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.backgroundColor = .white
        cv.dataSource = self
        cv.delegate = self
        return cv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        populateCollectionView()
        collectionView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.anchor(top: self.topAnchor, left: self.leftAnchor, bottom: self.bottomAnchor, right: self.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func searchTypeAndText(type: String, text: String, filtering: Bool) {
        isFiltering = filtering
        filteredData = dataArray.filter({( object : CustomObject) -> Bool in
            if type == "type" {
                return object.type.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
            } else {
                return object.type.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
            }
        })
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            self.collectionView.layoutSubviews()
        }
    }

    func populateCollectionView() {
    // load data into dataArray
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if isFiltering {
        // during searching this will be triggered and return the correct count for the filteredData
            return filteredData.count
        } else {
            return dataArray.count
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        var object: CustomObject
        // isFiltering is always false even when searching
        if isFiltering {
            // never called
            object = filteredData[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            // always called even when searching
            object = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        }
        // do cell things here
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width - 8, height: 120)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        let radius = cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius
        cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: cell.bounds, cornerRadius: radius).cgPath
    }
}
```

**Here's the code for MainFrame**

```swift
class MainFrame: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    let cellId = "cellId"

    let childFrameCell1Id = "cell1Id"

    let childFrameCell2Id = "cell2Id"

    var childFrameCell1: ChildFrameCell1!

    var childFrameCell2: ChildFrameCell2!

    lazy var topBar: CustomTopBar = {
        let tb = CustomTopBar()
        tb.mainFrame = self
        return tb
    }() // Top bar sliding indicator

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureView()
        configureSearchBar()
        configureCollectionView()
        setupTopBar()
    }

    func configureCollectionView() {
        if let flowLayout = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
            flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        }
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.register(ChildFrameCell1.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: childFrameCell1Id)
        collectionView.register(ChildFrameCell2.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: childFrameCell2Id)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 45, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 45, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollView.ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never

        childFrameCell1 = ChildFrameCell1()
        childFrameCell2 = ChildFrameCell2()
    }

    func setupTopBar() {
        // add top bar
    }

    func configureView() {
        // set up view
    }

    func configureSearchBar() {
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white
        searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = .white
        if let tf = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            tf.textColor = UIColor.white
            if let backgroundView = tf.subviews.first {
                backgroundView.backgroundColor = .white
                backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                backgroundView.clipsToBounds = true
            }
        }
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Type1", "Type2"]
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
        return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    }

    func isFiltering() -> Bool {
        let searchBarScopeIsFiltering = searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex != 0
        return searchController.isActive && (!searchBarIsEmpty() || searchBarScopeIsFiltering)

    }


    func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "Location") {
        let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: collectionView.contentOffset, size: collectionView.bounds.size)
        let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
        let visibleIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: visiblePoint)
        if visibleIndexPath?.row == 0 { 
// find the current view and parse search text into childFrame
            childFrameCell1.searchTypeAndText(type: scope, text: searchText, filtering: isFiltering())
        } else {
            childFrameCell2.searchTypeAndText(type: scope, text: searchText, filtering: isFiltering())
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2 // 2 pages
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let id: String

        currentView = indexPath.item
        if currentView == 0 {
            id = childFrameCell1Id
        } else {
            id = childFrameCell2Id
        }
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: id, for: indexPath) as! ChildFrameCell1
        cell.mainFrame = self
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - 50)
    }
}

extension MainFrame: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
        let scope = searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex]
        filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!, scope: scope)
        }
    }
}
extension MainFrame: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
        filterContentForSearchText(searchBar.text!, scope: searchBar.scopeButtonTitles![selectedScope])
    }
}
```

**ChildFrameCell2 is a subclass of ChildFrameCell1**

When i enter text in the search bar in the MainFrame, it doesn't reload the collectionView to the new filteredData even if filteredData contains data.
I've been trying many ways to do this but still unable to reload the collectionView.
I even tried using DispatchGroup but the result is still the same. Filtering is not an issue, everything works accordingly except for reloading the collectionView.

Thank you for reading this lengthy post.
If you need the code from the MainFrame do let me know.

Comment: yeah, link the mainframe code, we need to see where you're calling "searchTypeAndText" in the mainframe code.

Comment: @Loxx I added the relevant mainframe code. Thank you for reading.